# CSS multiple selectors without comma

Tags: css

I am alittle confuse about CSS Selectors, I understand that we can group multiple css selectors with a comma if they share similar attributes, but what about multiple css selectors without commas e.g like this:

```
.ui-datepicker-rtl { direction: rtl; }
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev { right: 2px; left: auto; }
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next { left: 2px; right: auto; }
```

Comment: Please take the time to read about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you use the comma, like

```
#menu, .item
```

you are saying:

> all elements whose id is menu AND all elements whose class is item

When you nest selectors without the comma, like

```
#menu .item
```

you are saying

> all elements that has class item inside a container whose id is menu

Comment: +1 Juan, though I don't mind learning how to fish, but your answer prevented many to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

This selects descendants.

`.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev` will pick all decendants of elements with class `ui-datepicker-rtl` who have class `ui-datepicker-prev`